# До какой версии Qt можно использовать бесплатно?

Tags: qt5, лицензирование

Есть проект, который делается для одного заказчика, в дальнейшем данный проект никак распространяться не будет. Можно ли использовать Qt без какой либо платы, если заказчику при этом будет предоставлен весь исходный код? Какую последнюю версию Qt можно испольдовать таким образом?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, в этом случае вы можете использовать Qt5 и под GPL, и под LGPLv3 (кроме тех частей, которые недоступны под LGPL). Посмотрите [их FAQ](https://www.qt.io/faq/tag/qt-open-source-licensing) в части "What are my obligations when using Qt under the LGPL?"